# How does C macro expansion work?

Tags: c, macros

let me explain my confusion with sample code

this is our macro

```
#define rsAssert(v)   if(!(v)) printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i" #v, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

**case 1:**

```
int main(void)
{
  rsAssert(0);
  return 0;
}
```

this case compiles succesfully

**case 2**

```
int main(void)
{
  rsAssert(0)  // note here ;  is not present
  return 0;
}
```

this also compiles succsfully
**Question 1:**

it means whether you write `rsAssert(0)` or `rsAssert(0);`  no difference between them?

---

then

**case 3**

```
int main()
{
  if(1)
    rsAssert(0);
  else 
    printf("mr.32");
  return 0;
}
```

here `rsassert(0);` is not going to compile [see [http://ideone.com/7dFv1]](http://ideone.com/7dFv1) but without `;` `rsasser(0)` works fine [see [http://ideone.com/8fehl]](http://ideone.com/8fehl)..

I am not getting what's going on with macro expansion here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not working in case 3 is because this is what is actually getting compiled:

```
int main()
{
if(1)
  if(!(v)) printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", #v, __FILE__, __LINE__);;
else 
  printf("mr.32");
return 0;
}
```

Note the extra semicolon at the end of the first printf from the macro.

Normally, with an if statement, it's followed by a single statement, or a block with { }.

But because of the extra ;, you have this:

```
if (...) 
    printf(...); ;
else
    printf(...);
return 0;
```

That extra semicolon is an empty statement, but is still a statement nonetheless.

You should remove the ; from the macro. Then things would make more sense.

Comment: oh thanks got it whole things.. in case 1 it has one more ; wich is empty statement and in case 2 is perfect but in case 2 using rsassert(0); case extra ; which create problem...

Comment: Yes. Simply, when looking at macro replacement in C, it's pretty much literally just copied in to the file. They don't really have any semantics of their own.

Answer (score 4):

This is the biggest reason I always enforce my programmers to use bodies on all of their if statements.

```
int main()
{
  if (1)
    if(!(0))
      printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", "0", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    else 
      printf("mr.32");
  return 0;
}
```

prevented by good coding standards

```
int main()
{
  if (1){
    if(!(0)){
      printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", "0", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
    }
    else {
      printf("mr.32");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Fixes that are low cost of change listed blow.

```
#define rsAssert(v) (printf( (!v)?"rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i":"", #v, __FILE__, __LINE__))
```

This will work but will always do a printf.

```
#define rsAssert(v) ((!v)?printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", #v, __FILE__, __LINE__):0)
```

This will only print out if you trip the assert, but is messy looking

Also consider the following!

```
if( rand()%2 )
  FooLog("Hello World");
ImportantFunction();

#if DEBUG
#define FooLog printf
#else
#define FooLog //
#endif
```

In release, the important function works 100% of the time 50% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working at all in case 3, I expect. Do the expansion by hand (and reindent for it to make sense):

```
int main()
{
  if (1)
    if(!(0))
      printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", "0", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    else 
      printf("mr.32");
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the `else` ends up with the wrong `if` statement. If you want a macro containing an `if` statement to work, you need to make it look like a simple statement.  Wrapping it in `do... while(0)` is idiomatic:

```
#define rsAssert(v)                                                         \
    do {                                                                    \
      if(!(v))                                                              \
        printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i", #v, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(1)
  rsAssert(0); // Original semicolon
else 
  ....
```

expands to

```
if(1)
   if(!(v)) printf("rsAssert failed: %s, in %s at %i",
       #v, __FILE__, __LINE__);; // Notice the extra semicolon. The extra from the
                                 // macro expansion.
else
    ....
```

This extra semicolon is causing an new empty statement. Since there is no `{}`, for if statement, `else` is not immediately followed and is what compiler is complaining. So, do -

```
if(1)
{
  rsAssert(0);
}
 else 
  ....
```